# Web scraping con una ERP almacenado en una URL

Tags: python, r, scrapy, report

Tengo un proyecto entre manos, pero no se como iniciar dado que he estado pensado en dos lenguajes, Python y R.

Actualmente todos los días descargo 10 tipos de reportes que están alojados en una ERP, en la empresa donde trabajo, la idea que quiero desarrollar es poder descargar esto de manera automática.

En la primera imagen muestra la ventana de inicio, la idea es que mi máquina se loguee automaticamente, luego como aparece en la segunda y tercera imagen busque el reporte que quiero, luego sale una ventana la cual hay que parametrizar: donde se selecciona que columnas quiero en el reporte, el separador, seleccionar: Export column as locale neutral. 
Esto se podrá hacer con Python o con R, si saben si se puede, me podrían indicar que paquete se requiere para esto, y algún ejemplo, si lo tienen. Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con python o con r, la desición me parece pasa, por como luego vas a utilizar estos datos. Lo que si es fundamental es usar un paquete o librería que no trabaje con el html estático sino que pueda interactuar a la manera de un browser. Esto por que tienes un proceso de login, y que seguramente se trate de páginas dinámicas. Te recomiendo `Selenium` haya paquetes para ambos lenguajes.: https://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Gracias, voy a buscar el paquete que me recomendaste.
Un abrazo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Se puede hacer en Python, las librerías que hay son:
* Request: es buena para comenzar y entender el mundo del scraping o para hacer algo rápido
* Scrapy: es la más recomendable para hacer scraping
* Selenium: solo se usa si necesitas renderizar el Java de la página, ya que las otras dos no lo realizan. Por contra es más lento que las otras dos librerías.

Te recomiendo que te hagas algún curso en python de como hacer scraping ya que es sencillo lo que tu buscas hacer, pero si no sabes nada, te perderas. Por último te dejo un trozo de código, de como sería rellenar un formulario, en este caso es de la página [quotes.to.scrape.com](http://quotes.toscrape.com/). Es una página que se usa para aprender y entrenar haciendo scrapping

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "login"
    allowed_domains = ["quotes.toscrape.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://quotes.toscrape.com/login',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        csrf_token = response.xpath(
        '//*[@name="csrf_token"]/@value').extract_first()

        yield FormRequest('http://quotes.toscrape.com/login',
                          formdata={'csrf_token': csrf_token,
                                    'username': 'foobar',
                                    'password': 'foobar'},
                          callback=self.parse_after_login)

    def parse_after_login(self, response):
        open_in_browser(response)
```